# How do I get rid of an unknown and unwanted top row with symbol in table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

As per this screenshot:
[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heQdd.png)
...can't find it in the css or the html... not sure what I did to make it appear... it shows up on different pcs and browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Periods of the Bible</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cyberspacelinkdock.com/Images/kofgflag.ico?ver=2.0" type="image/x-icon"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        table.tableizer-table {
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .tableizer-table td {
            padding: 8px;
            margin: 7px;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
        }
        .tableizer-table th {
            font-size: 16px;
            background-color: #104E8B;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .tableizer-table tr {
        border: solid;
        border-width: 2px 0;
        }
            </style>
</head>
<body lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<center>
<table class="tableizer-table" border=1 frame=void rules=rows cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="page-break-before: always>
    <thead>
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
            <th colspan="5">Sixteen Historical Periods of the Bible</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:125pt" border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b>NAME<b></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:308pt" border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b>DESCRIPTION<b></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:116pt" border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b>SCRIPTURE</b></p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:80pt" border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b>TIME SPAN</b></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; align:left padding: 0in"><p><b>YEARS&nbsp;</b></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>1. Ante-Diluvian</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the creation to the
                flood</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Genesis 1 - 6</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 4004 - 2348</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>1656</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>2. Post-Diluvian</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the flood to the
                call of Abraham</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Genesis 7 - 11</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 2348 - 1921</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>427</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><b><i><p>3. Patriarchial</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the call of Abraham
                to the descent into Egypt</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Genesis 12 - 50</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1921 - 1706</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>215</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i><b><i>4. Bondage</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the descent into
                Egypt to the exodus</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Exodus 1 -12</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1706 - 1491</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>215</4center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>5. Wilderness Wandering</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the exodus to the
                entrance into Canaan</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Ex. 2 - Deu. 34</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1491 - 1451</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>40</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>6. Conquest of Canaan</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the entrance into
                Canaan to the time of the Judges</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Judges 1 - 2</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1451 - 1400</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>51</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>7. Judges</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the beginning of
                the Judges to the beginning of the Kingdom</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Judges 3 - 1 Samuel 8</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1400 - 1095</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>305</center></center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>8. Kingdom of Israel</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the beginning of
                the Kingdom to the division of the Kingdom</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>1 Samuel 9 - 1 Kings 11;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 1095 - 975</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>120</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>1 Chron. 10 - 2 Chron. 9</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>9. Two Kingdoms</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the division of the
                Kingdom to the fall of Israel</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>1 Kings 12 - 2 Kings 18;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 975 - 722</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>253</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>2 Chron. 10 - 29</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>10. Kingdom of Judah</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the fall of Israel
                to the fall of Judah</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>2 Kings 21 - 25;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 722 - 587</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>135</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>2 Chron. 33 - 36</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>11. Babylonian Captivity</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the fall of Judah
                to the restoration of Jerusalem</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Isaiah.; Jer.; Ez.;
                Dan.</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 587 - 537</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>50</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>12. Restoration</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the return to
                Jerusalem to the end of the Old Testament</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Ez/Neh/Esth/Hag/Zech.</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 537 - 445</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>92</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>13. Between Testaments</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the end of the Old
                Testament to the birth of Christ</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>-</center></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 445 - 4</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>441</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><b><i>14. When He Walked</b></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>From the birth of Jesus
                to His crucifixion</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>Matthew - John</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>B.C. 4 - A.D. 30</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center>33</center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor = "#c9c3a0";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><strong><font color="red"><i>15. The Last Days</stron></font></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="red">From the ascension to
                the days of vengeance</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="red">Acts - Revelation</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="red">A.D. 30 - 70</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center><font color="red">40</font></center></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor = "#c9c3a0";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><strong><font color="red"><i> of the Old Covenant Age</stron></font></i></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <<td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor = "#366092";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><strong><i><font color="#FFC000">16. The Gospel Age</strong></i></font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="#FFC000">From the final end of the old covenant to the second coming</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="#FFC000">Isaiah 60; 65:17; 66:22</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="#FFC000">A.D. 70 - ...</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><center><font color="#FFC000">?</center></font></p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor = "#366092";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="#FFC000">Habakkuk 2:14</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor = "#366092";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="#FFC000">Luke 22:20; Rev.21:2</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor = "#7190B5";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white"><center><strong>*** The Eternal State ***</strong></font></center></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="blue"><font color="white">From the second coming
                unto timeless eternity</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white">Isaiah 25:8</font></p>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white"><b><center>&infin;</b></center></font></p>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor = "#7190B5"; border-bottom: none;>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white">Romans 8:21</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor = "#7190B5";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white">1 Cor 15:28; 1John 3:2b</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor = "#7190B5";>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p><font color="white">Revelation 21:4</font></p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="border: none; padding: 0in"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table></center><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried adjusting css styles and html tags; learning a lot but can't figure it out.
Its only the top row that's a problem but I posted the entire code just in case; everything displays perfectly except for the top row.

Comment: This is a very serious question: Which IDE do you use? There are *countless* syntax errors in your code, including misnesting and usage of deprecated tags/attributes, all of which can be avoided with a decent IDE.

Comment: I use both Atom and Notepad++ but haven't learned the interfaces well enough to make either much better than regular Notepad... can you recommend and "IDE for dummies"? I acknowledge that I need to improve and am embarrassingly pathetic at this point though I do basically understand  the deprecation issue. For example I finally overcame laziness and started using <strong> instead of <b> but sometimes I forget.  Looking forward to resolving the misnesting. Thanks.

Comment: For web development, I suggest [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (free, lightweight, general) and [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (paid, dedicated). Both have excellent plugins support.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
<table [...] style="page-break-before: always>
                                          --^^
```

You are missing a closing " in your style attribute.
It should be

```
<table [...] style="page-break-before: always">
```

Comment: It isn't the only problem though: There are several lines with that missing "; but the real reason for your symbol issue lies in
"<<td style="border: none; padding: 0in"><p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>>"

Comment: You rock RG!... that was it... fixed the double < you pointed out, then search for >> and found the other one, and so the (embarrassing) problem is solved. As InSync pointed out I need to learn how to use an IDE to pick up "typos" at least... there are so many colors; suppose I need to customize the error checking interface. Thanks!